# Is "quick brining" as effective as an overnight soak?

Tags: meat, brining

I recently came across this article, [Quickly Brine Chicken When You Don't Have Much Time](http://lifehacker.com/5661820/quickly-brine-chicken-when-you-dont-have-much-time), which suggests 2-3 hours in a 10% brine, followed by a 1-hour rest. Does this work? If so, are there any trade-offs over compared to using a longer, weaker brine?

Comment: @user1575 - could you clarify what information you are looking for further, please?

Comment: @user1575: I've tried to flesh out your question a bit... If this isn't what you were looking for, please clarify!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the source (Michael Ruhlman) and that it was linked by Seriouseats, I am willing to bet cash money that not only does it work exactly as stated, it will provide spectacular results.